# How can we search through the list of completed Windows updates?

Tags: windows-vista, search, windows-update

After installing Windows update, **Control Panel** → **Windows Update** shows the update history review:

[image][<kbd>**Enlarge**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtNpA.png)

How can we do a "search" through this list?

For example, I would like to filter by "security" updates in the list, and it should show me (among others):

[image][<kbd>**Enlarge**</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB5ka.png)

Is there a built-in way to achieve this? Or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can search from registry via [`reg`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490984.aspx) and [`findstr`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx) command line tool.

`reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s | findstr /i "DisplayName.*Security.*Update"`

#### Example

```
C:\>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s | findstr /i "DisplayName.*Security.*Update"
    DisplayName REG_SZ  Security Update for CAPICOM (KB931906)
    DisplayName REG_SZ  Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended (KB2416472)

C:\>reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" /s | findstr "安全更新"
    DisplayName REG_SZ  Windows Internet Explorer 8 安全更新 (KB2183461)
    DisplayName REG_SZ  Windows XP 安全更新 (KB2412687)
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will get what you want where you were looking.

I think the best you will do is to go to `Control Panel>Programs>Programs and Features>View Installed Updates` and sort on the date. It has quite a bit more information.

[image]